# Starttime and endtime

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

i have paramters fields as starttime(=DateAdd("d",-1,now())) and endtime (now()) and status( as dropdown ex:running,succededtec,.) in my report.... when i run the report with the whole timestamp it is working as expected but if i give only date in both the fields without time then am not getting last one days data( for example if starttime is 6/14/2017 and endtime is 6/18/2017 am getting data till 6/17/2017 only) .....one more scenario is when I have no endtime (like status is running we have no endtime) then am getting that.Can anyone help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time defaults to `00:00:00` if not included.

So basically when you're comparing say

`06-18-2017 07:52:11 <= 6-18-2017`

you're actually comparing

`06-18-2017 07:52:11 <= 6-18-2017 00:00:00`

Since the time defaults to zero, and you will never get any 6-18 results returned unless they happened at exactly midnight.  Set the timestamp in your compare, or use 6-19 as your compare date instead (with the risk of including a random record that happened at exactly midnight on 6-19).

Comment: This is what I gave my endtime in where condition (DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms,end_time),cast(end_time As datetime) )
 <= case when isnull(@EndTime,'')<>'' then cast(@EndTime AS datetime) else getdate() end.... how will I be able to change it now to set the default to 11:59:59???.... basically my starttime and endtime are not always the same .... I gave calendar control to change it .

Comment: Assuming @EndTime is a date, try this `...then cast(cast(@enddate as varchar(19)) + ' 23:59:59' as datetime) else getdate()`  This will cast @enddate to a string, add the max time, then cast the whole string back to a datetime.  Might not even need the cast back to datetime, but shouldn't hurt.